# iterate over specific amount of element in queryset that was passed through to template

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-queryset

Im passing a queryset (in my case usercomments) to a template. This queryset could theoratically contain a lot of comments. Now i want to show the elements of the query as a list. I can show a specific amount eg. 3 with the help of the slice function in django template language, thasts no problem(I iterate with a for loop over the queryset(as shown in the code)). But now i want a Button that says "Show More", and everytime the button gets pressed the list expands by 3 elements.

I simplified the code shown below a bit.

If some information is missing or this post does not match the "stackoverflow ruels" let me know it (its my first post).

I tried to change somehow the number in the for loop but i think that wont work with django template language

```
{% for com in comments|slice:":3" %} //I want to increas that number with a button
    <li>
        <span class="name">{{com.name}}</span>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This looks more like something you want to do at the frontend (so with JavaScript) than letting Django limit the items to display.

Comment: Yes excactly I also tried to find someting in the internet to handle it with javascript but with no luck